# Texture appearing on wrong surface SDL2

Tags: sdl-2

I have an issue where **'at random'** the character sometimes appears in the text box. This happens when I destroy the ftexture (text) and create a new sprite texture (Main character).

If anyone might have an idea why it does this? As I mentioned, it is a very rare occurrence and difficult to replicate reliably. When it happens, if I move my mouse over another hover able object, it then returns to normal again.

The code where this happens is here:

```
  if (playerMessage != true && interactionMessage == "") {                          
                       
                        if (gdSprite.x < gd && gdSprite.y < y || gdSprite.x > gd && gdSprite.y > y) {   
                            playerIsMoving = 0;                            
                        }
                       
                        else {              
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(Textures::spriteTexture);
                                Textures::spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Textures::spriteDown1);** //Makes player face you when you are hovering.**                           
                             
                        }
                       
                            interactionMessage = pob.HoverObjects(x, y, scene, gd, gy);                            
                    }
                   
                    if (interactionMessage != "" && playerIsMoving !=1) {                        
                        pi.InteractionControllerHover(interactionMessage);
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This appears to have fixed the problem. I nulled the ftexture after destroying it.

```
  case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:      
                    //Event Motion coordinates. Where the mouse moves on the screen.
                    x = event.motion.x;
                    y = event.motion.y;
                    gd = gdSprite.x;
                    gy = gdSprite.y;

                    if (event.motion.y > 589 && event.motion.x < 289 || event.motion.y == gy + 90 || event.motion.y == gy - 90 || event.motion.x == gd + 90 || event.motion.x == gd - 90) {                                                  
                        playerMessage = false;
                    }

                    //This addresses the movement to the left issue where the player never reaches to destination and prevents hover interaction.
                    if (playerMessage != true && interactionMessage == "") {                          
                        //Prevents sleep from kicking in when walking to a target.
                        if (gdSprite.x < gd && gdSprite.y < y || gdSprite.x > gd && gdSprite.y > y) {   
                            playerIsMoving = 0;                            
                        }                         
                        else {              
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                                ftexture = nullptr;
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(Textures::spriteTexture);
                                Textures::spriteTexture = nullptr;
                                Textures::spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Textures::spriteDown1); //Makes player face you when you are hovering.                                                                                                                                        
                        }
                       
                            interactionMessage = pob.HoverObjects(x, y, scene, gd, gy);                            
                    }
                   
                    if (interactionMessage != "" && playerIsMoving !=1) {                        
                        pi.InteractionControllerHover(interactionMessage);
                    }                 
             
                    break;                    
                
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    case SDLK_q:
                    gameover = 1;
                    break;
                }
                break;          
            }
            
    }
```